# Merging JavaScript objects in an array where data matches

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of objects, where I'd like to merge some objects if certain data matches. Here is the array:

```
0: {name: "1", qty: "3", measurement: "Tbsp"}
1: {name: "paprika", qty: "2", measurement: "Tbsp"}
2: {name: "onion", qty: "1", measurement: "cup"}
3: {name: "tomatoes", qty: "16", measurement: "oz"}
4: {name: "tomatoes", qty: "16", measurement: "oz"}
```

I'd like to match based on the name and measurement keys. I.e. if the `name` is the same AND the `measurement` is the same, then combine the object and total the `qty`, where the resulting object would be:

```
0: {name: "1", qty: "3", measurement: "Tbsp"}
1: {name: "paprika", qty: "2", measurement: "Tbsp"}
2: {name: "onion", qty: "1", measurement: "cup"}
3: {name: "tomatoes", qty: "32", measurement: "oz"}
```

I've tried it a few ways using `.includes()` and `.some()` but haven't managed with any success yet. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for the array `reduce` method. The following can be used to determine if our accumulator already has the desired item. If so, add the quantity. If not, push the item onto the accumulator array.

```js
const items = [
  {name: "1", qty: 3, measurement: "Tbsp"}, 
  {name: "paprika", qty: 2, measurement: "Tbsp"},
  {name: "onion", qty: 1, measurement: "cup"},
  {name: "tomatoes", qty: 16, measurement: "oz"},
  {name: "tomatoes", qty: 16, measurement: "oz"}
];

const combined = items.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const found = acc.find(item => item.name === el.name && item.measurement === el.measurement);
  if (found) {
    found.qty += el.qty;
  } else {
    acc.push(el);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(combined);
```

Comment: This solved my problem excellently. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Approach using a Map and concatenating the name and measurement to create the unique keys so they look like `"tomatoes|oz"`

```js
const groupItems = (arr) => {
  const m = new Map;      
  arr.forEach(o => {
      const k = `${o.name}|${o.measurement}`;
      // if the key already exists just add current qty 
      // otherwise set new entry using current object
      m.has(k) ? m.get(k).qty += o.qty : m.set(k, {...o});
  });      
  return [...m.values()];
}

console.log(groupItems(data))
```

```html
<script>
const data=[{name:"1",qty:3,measurement:"Tbsp"},{name:"paprika",qty:2,measurement:"Tbsp"},{name:"onion",qty:1,measurement:"cup"},{name:"tomatoes",qty:16,measurement:"oz"},{name:"tomatoes",qty:16,measurement:"oz"}];
</script>
```